# memcaching not loading in my windows 8

Tags: php, windows-8, memcached, wamp

i have done everything written in this article.I checked multiple times.

```
http://rutfin.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/installing-memcache-on-windows-8-for-wamp-server/
```

but still memcached is not working for me. I cant find memcached in my phpinfo() either.

I have checked windows Services and a service named memcached server is running there. I have checked php extention in my wamp and it is also "checkmarked".

[image: service screenshot]

[image: wamp screenshot]

Any other suggestion please.

Comment: What code have you written to put data into memcache? Is is listed in phpinfo()?

Comment: If the memcached service is failing to start, check the windows event log for error message from it.

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, memcached is not listed in phpinfo() @AlisterBulman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i figured it myself.

Wamp 2.4 has two php.ini files.

```
Location 1 =  D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini
Location 2 =  D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini
```

When i clicked wamp icon > php  > php.ini it was saving data in Location 1.
This is a wrong file.

Correct php.ini file is in location 2.
I opened Location 2 and added "extension=php_memcache.dll" and  it worked like charm.

I hope it helps other users too.